# Is there any way that dynamic tags showing in source code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any way for showing dynamic data in html source code??
Could you help me?

Comment: There isn't. The source code is how your browser receives the data from the server without any modifications and without running it.

Comment: Use the browser debugging (press F12) **Elements tab**, not view-source.  View-source reloads from the server so won't include anything that's been run after the initial load.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Data in HTML can be embedded using JavaScript or jQuery

```
jQuery Code: $("p").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var node = document.createElement("div");               
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Hello World");       
node.appendChild(textnode);                             
document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
```